# How to rename my CVS project?

Tags: cvs

I just started using CVS to manage my source files. After finishing my school assignment, I found out that I had used the wrong project name in my cvsroot. Since the submit system is looking for a specific project name in the directory, it denies my submission although my source files are all in that directory. Is there a way to change the name of the project in CVS? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using CVS for a new project?  There are *much* better tools available.  For the love of God, look into git or mercurial or subversion.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure everything is checked in, and best to coordinate this with any other users
2. If you are in Eclipse, close the project (optional)
3. On the cvs server, rename the directory name for your project in CVSROOT to whatever you want (mv existing_directory new_directory)
4. Back on the cvs client, import the project as usual (it will be a new project, of course, named new_directory in this example)
5. (Optional) Delete the old directory on the client once you are sure all the files made it (highly likely!)

NOTE: Of course, any other projects referencing the old directory name will be "broken" and have to now reference the new directory name

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the file in CVSROOT.
CVS is dumb, it don't care renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a new cvs repository with the proper name and copy your source files over to the new one, then add and commit. Is the history of your particular project important for the reviewers?

Answer (score 0):

1. rename the directory name for your project in CVSROOT to newProjectName
2. back to your working directory, find the file CVS/Repository, open it and change the project name in there to newProjectName

that's how I did it, and it worked.